# How to combine two or multiple JSON objects into one in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api

Is it possible to add new data in API JSON response in AngularJS? I am consuming a REST API which returns country details, but I want to add more details to it.

After the API call, I'm getting this response:
[image]

There are few empty fields (red arrow). I need to fill it up using another API into each respective country, and also add new keys such as "id" etc if possible.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this? and how?

---

Here is the code:

### Api service.js  (data which are going to be added)

```
$http.get("https://api.../getfile/rohit/fw18countries").success(function(data) {
    teams = data.teams;
    //console.log(data);
    /* shuffle(teams); */
});

return {
    GetTeams: function(){
        return teams;
    },
    get: function(teamId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
            if (teams[i].id === parseInt(teamId)) {
                return teams[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Controller.js

```
/* all teams data */
$scope.Allteams = wcAPI.GetTeams(); 

/* REST API call */
$http.get("http://api.../v1/competitions/467/fixtures")
  .then(function(data) {
      $scope.country = data;
      console.log($scope.country);
  });
```

So now, I need to update `$scope.country` (REST API data) using `$scope.Allteams` (my static data) with respective fields as mentioned above. Need to merge them respectively.

Comment: Can you show your code that calls the API? You will need to get the data from the result and modify it in your javascript. It will be easier to explain by modifying your code example (when provided)

Comment: @AnthW  Thanks, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with the following code. Looping through the data arrays and findig the right one. Then adding all values to the object.

```
 for(var i = 0; i< $scope.country.length; i++) {
    //Find the right index from $scope.country
    for(var j = 0; j< $scope.Allteams.length; j++) {
        // TODO here you have to campare by right value
        if($scope.country[i].id == $scope.Allteams[j].teamId) {
            for(var key in $scope.AllTeams[j]) {

                if(!$scope.Allteams[j].hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

                //Adds the value to the object
                $scope.country[i][key] = $scope.Allteams[j][key];
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can I add for each country, eg russia to russia, South Africa to south africa etc.

Comment: @RohitGhosh For this you have to change the line under the TODO comment. For example $scope.country[i].name == $scope.Allteams[j].team